# Tag discipline and convention

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I stumbled upon the tag [food-and-drink](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-and-drink). Since there are no special language rules for words around that theme, I edited 10 questions, marked with it, and replaced the tag or just deleted it.

We don't have tags for gardening, sports, travel and traffic and so on either and this should remain that way. I encourage searching for such semantic tags and getting rid of them, as long as it is not too much work.

Edge cases might be collected and discussed here.

---

Ich bin heute auf den Tag [food-and-drink](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-and-drink) gestoßen. Da es keine anderen Sprachregeln für Begriffe um das Thema gibt habe ich beschlossen alle 10 Fragen dazu zu überarbeiten, und das Tag zu löschen/zu ersetzen.

Wir haben auch keine Tags Garten, Sport, Reise und Verkehr usw. und das sollte auch so bleiben. Ich ermuntere weitere Beispiele schlechter Tags zu suchen und diese zu eliminieren, bevor sie so populär sind, dass ihre Löschung und Ersetzung große Arbeit wird.

Zweifelsfälle können hier gesammelt und diskutiert werden.